# Eembedding of product $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^3$ into $\mathbb{R}^6$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

It is easy to see that $\mathbb{S}^n$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and therefore $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^3$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^7$.

The question is how to prove that $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^3$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Comment: Quick remark: consider the quadratic form $q(x) := x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-x_4^2-x_5^2-x_6^2-x_7^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^7$. It induces an algebraic manifold $\{q = 0\}$ in $\mathcal{P}_6 (\mathbb{R})$ which is $\mathbb{S}_2 \times \mathbb{S}_3$. This gives you an embedding into a dimension 6 projective manifold. Not sure how to go from there, though.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{S}^{n}$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ as 
$$x_{0}^2+\dots+x_{n}^2=1$$

Hence $\mathbb{S}^{2}\times\mathbb{S}^{3}$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^{7}$ as
$$\begin{cases}x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1\\x_4^2+x_5^2+x_6^2=1\end{cases}$$
In particular $\mathbb{S}^{2}\times\mathbb{S}^{3}$ embeds in the $6-$sphere of radius $\sqrt{2}$
$$x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2+x_5^2+x_6^2=2$$
in $\mathbb{R}^{7}$. 
Composing this standard embedding with the stereographic projection of this $\mathbb{S}^6\subset\mathbb{R}^7$ from one of the poles you get the embedding in $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Comment: Dario, your solution is incorrect because the stereographic projection is not a embedding ( $\mathbb{S}^6$ is compact).

Comment: It is not an embedding of $\mathbb{S}^6$, but the point is that it is a diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{S}^6\setminus\{p\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Comment: As fail a point then can't be considered the solution to the initial question.

Comment: You need an embedding of $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^3$ into $\mathbb{R}^6$. What you have is an embedding into $\mathbb{S}^6$, that is for free an embedding into $\mathbb{S}^6\setminus\{p\}$. You don't need a diffeomorphism from the whole $\mathbb{S}^6$, but just from $\mathbb{S}^6\setminus\{p\}$.

Comment: Try to think at a lower dimensional analogue: if you have and embedding of a curve into $\mathbb{S}^{2}$, the stereographic projection gives you an embedding in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$...

Comment: The problem is that the stereographic projection is not a embedding

Comment: I agree, but once you have an embedding into $\mathbb{S}^{6}\setminus\{p\}$ you **don't** need another embedding you need a **diffeomorphism** from $\mathbb{S}^{6}\setminus\{p\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{6}$ and the stereographic projection works for that.